# Shift cells right like in Excel in SAS

Tags: sas, data-cleaning

have dataframe that looks like this...

[what i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ckt1t.png)

The index value for country "USA" is NULL. I need to delete it and shift the values on right "905094" to left. So that the final dataframe will look like this...

[final](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdFkQ.png)

In Excel, I can simply right click to choose "delete..." and select shift cells left option. Is there similar functionality in SAS EG?

I tried working with array's but maybe i am not experienced enough.

Comment: Pictures of data are in general not useful.  Yours even more so as I cannot tell what your data is from that picture.  Please just post the data as a simple data step that make the dataset.   Is the goal to work from a DATASET?  Or are you attempting to read a TEXT file that looks like your photograph?  Show the data step you tried to use to read the file.